# AppendTo() element, jQuery CSS class change not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a issue that I can't figure out for days now. I have two elements, logo & "Go Back" button in my header.

Now, I want those two elements to do exactly the same thing. On click, show the same drop down. I don't want to replicate my code so I am trying to move the element and assign correct classes on click.

I managed to move my element on click properly, however on one element the `display: none` is not changing and I am really confused why not.

I want the drop down to appear under the element that was clicked. So, if you click the "logo", the drop-down will be moved to "logo" element and will appear under the logo, if the "go back" is clicked, the drop-down will be moved to "go back" element and appear under that element.

**On click, the elements change so they look exactly the same, however, the `display: none` property wont change on the "Go back" element. Can anyone tell me why?**

```js
jQuery("#checkout-header-count").click(function() {
  jQuery("#checkout-header-logo").removeClass("checkout-prepend-dropdown");
  jQuery("#checkout-header-count").addClass("checkout-prepend-dropdown");
  jQuery(".checkout-prepend-dropdown-content").appendTo(jQuery("#checkout-header-count"));
});

jQuery("#checkout-header-logo").click(function() {
  jQuery("#checkout-header-count").removeClass("checkout-prepend-dropdown");
  jQuery("#checkout-header-logo").addClass("checkout-prepend-dropdown");
  jQuery(".checkout-prepend-dropdown-content").appendTo(jQuery("#checkout-header-logo"));
});

jQuery(".checkout-prepend-dropdown").click(function() {
  if (jQuery(".checkout-prepend-dropdown-content").css('display') == 'block') {
    jQuery(".checkout-prepend-dropdown-content").css("display", "none")
  } else if (jQuery(".checkout-prepend-dropdown-content").css('display') == 'none') {
    jQuery(".checkout-prepend-dropdown-content").css("display", "block");
  }
});

jQuery('.checkout-prepend-dropdown-content').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
jQuery(".checkout-prepend-dropdown").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  jQuery('.checkout-prepend-dropdown-content').show();
});
jQuery(document).click(function(e) {
  jQuery('.checkout-prepend-dropdown-content').hide();
});
jQuery("#returnCheckout").click(function() {
  jQuery('.checkout-prepend-dropdown-content').hide();
});
```

```css
.checkout-prepend-dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #4E4D4D;
  color: white;
  left: -70px;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 20;
}

.checkout-prepend-dropdown-content>div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.checkout-prepend-dropdown-content>div>a {
  color: #9C2CA8;
}

.checkout-prepend-dropdown-content>div>a:hover {
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkout-prepend-wrapper">
  <div style="display: inline-block; padding: 0 100px;" id="checkout-header-logo" class="checkout-prepend-dropdown">
    <img src="/media/logo/stores/1/logo_vv.png" alt="Logo" />
    <div class="checkout-prepend-dropdown-content">
      <p>Warning! You are about to leave the checkout!</p>
      <div id="returnCheckout" class="vvButton">Return to checkout</div>
      <div class="vvButton"><a href="/checkout/cart">Go back to basket</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; padding: 0 100px;" id="checkout-header-count">Go back</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't figure out what you exactly want but I can see that you attach multiple click event to the same element... example you're attaching three click events to the logo div

Comment: I dont get the problem either.. care to explain?

Comment: I am sorry that it don't make sense... When you click on the "logo" the drop down appears. When you click on the "Go back" the drop down appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you could create a function that does your flow logic and attaches it to the click event of both buttons, like this you'll be sure that the buttons will do the same job :

```
jQuery("#checkout-header-count, #checkout-header-logo").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    toggleDropdown();
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  jQuery("#checkout-header-count, #checkout-header-logo").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    toggleDropdown(this);
  });


  jQuery('.checkout-prepend-dropdown-content').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  jQuery(document).click(function(e) {
    jQuery('.checkout-prepend-dropdown-content').hide();
  });
});

function toggleDropdown(clicked_element) {
  jQuery("#checkout-header-logo").removeClass("checkout-prepend-dropdown");
  jQuery("#checkout-header-count").addClass("checkout-prepend-dropdown");

  jQuery(".checkout-prepend-dropdown-content").appendTo($(clicked_element));

  if (jQuery(".checkout-prepend-dropdown-content").is(':visible')) {
    jQuery(".checkout-prepend-dropdown-content").hide();
  } else {
    jQuery(".checkout-prepend-dropdown-content").show();
  }
}
```

```css
.checkout-prepend-dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #4E4D4D;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 20;
}

.checkout-prepend-dropdown-content>div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.checkout-prepend-dropdown-content>div>a {
  color: #9C2CA8;
}

.checkout-prepend-dropdown-content>div>a:hover {
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkout-prepend-wrapper">
  <div style="display: inline-block; padding: 0 100px;" id="checkout-header-logo" class="checkout-prepend-dropdown">
    <img src="/media/logo/stores/1/logo_vv.png" alt="Logo" />
    <div class="checkout-prepend-dropdown-content">
      <p>Warning! You are about to leave the checkout!</p>
      <div id="returnCheckout" class="vvButton">Return to checkout</div>
      <div class="vvButton"><a href="/checkout/cart">Go back to basket</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; padding: 0 100px;" id="checkout-header-count">Go back
  </div>
```

Comment: Oh man! This is what I was trying to achieve for days now!!! I tired all sorts of different ways... You are my hero!

Comment: Glad I could help brother, HAPPY CODING.

Comment: Coding can be very frustrating sometimes haha :) Thank you once more :) enjoy your day!

Comment: Hey, I thought it was the solution, but it came out not to be exactly what I wanted. In your code, which ever element you click, the drop-down will appear under the "go back", however, I want the drop down to appear under which ever element was clicked... If that makes sense... So, if you click the logo, the drop-down will be moved to "logo" element and appear under the logo, if the "go back" is clicked, the drop-down will be moved to "go back" element and appear under that element. Check my snippet now, IO hope it makes more sense now. Sorry to keep bothering you :/

Comment: I have unaccepted your answer so as you are away, someone else might help me out... Sorry :(

Comment: Don't worry you did the right move, check my updated snippet now.

Comment: I wish, you were right next to me so I could shake your hand. Pure awesomeness